# Bash script - Take system output and use it as a variable

Tags: bash, db2, grep

Pretty simple question, I'm trying to get some output after executing a command and use it again.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo what's the source db name?
read SOURCE
echo what's the target db name?
read TARGET
db2 backup db $SOURCE online compress include logs
READ SOME OF THIS LINE = SOURCE
db2 restore database $SOURCE taken at $DB2TIME into $TARGET
```

the line "READ SOME OF THIS LINE" outputs like this:
Backup successful. The timestamp for this backup image is : 20100906142221
I think a grep command would do it, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: You have posted two followups as *answers*. They should be posted as edits to your original question. If you want a particular user to see your followups you should address a comment to them by attaching it to an answer they've left or by using @username in a comment. You could say something like `@dennis: please see my edited question for additional information. Remember, on these sites, answers are intended to be answers to the question rather than answers to other answers or comments.

Comment: @dennis thanks dennis, the problem was that when I reply to an answer I loose all my editing options so if i want to put code and highlighting in the formatting looks terrible - is there a way to have formatting in a reply comment?

Comment: just post it in a comment anyway. You'll get some helpful person who'll incorporate that back into your question if you don't have enough rep to edit your questions yourself.

Comment: As I said in my comment above, post them as edits to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, you capture the output of a command with `$()` (or backticks, but I prefer the former since you can nest them):

```
pax> xx=$(ls -1 | grep bac)

pax> echo "..${xx}.."
..backup0.sh
backup1.sh..
```

So, in your particular case you'd be looking at something like:

```
timestamp=$(db2 backup db $SOURCE online compress include logs 2>&1
    | tee /tmp/output
    | grep 'image is'
    | awk '{print $11}')
```

Keep in mind I've split that across multiple lines for readability but it should go on a single line. As to how it works:

- The `2>&1` combines standard output and error.
- The `tee` will ensure you have the entire output stored somewhere.
- The `grep` will give you the relevant line.
- The `awk` will print out only `20100906142221`.
- The `xx=$(...)` will take that and assign it to `xx`.

You may need to fine-tune some of the command if your output is slightly different to what you've stated but that should be a good start.

---

Based on comments, here's what you need to start with:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo what's the source db name?
read SOURCE
echo what's the target db name?
read TARGET
db2 backup db $SOURCE online compress include logs 2>&1 | tee /tmp/db_bkp_$$
DB2TIME=$(cat /tmp/db_bkp_$$ | grep 'image is' | awk '{print $11}')
rm -rf /tmp/db_bkp_$$
db2 restore database $SOURCE taken at $DB2TIME into $TARGET
```

This will execute the DB2 command sending output and error to both the terminal *and* the temporary file (`$$` gives you the current process ID to avoid file name collisions). You then extract the date/time from the temporary file then delete that file.

Then you use the date/time.

Comment: Instead of `$11` why not use `-F:`? You could also let `awk` do what you have `grep` doing. `tee ... | awk -F: '/image is/{print $2}'`

Comment: sorry I'm a noob at this, please see my reply above - this seems to be executing that command twice somehow. @dennis I'll have to try it that way and see if i get the desired result in only one execution

Comment: No problems, @edumike. It's because you _are_ actually executing that line twice. You should only do it within the `timestamp=...` line. That will execute the command, pipe the full output into /tmp/output and set the variable correctly. If you want the full output after that, just `cat /tmp/output`.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with @pax's answer, your code now becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo what's the source db name?
read SOURCE
echo what's the target db name?
read TARGET
DB2TIME=$(db2 backup db $SOURCE online compress include logs)
# you have read it above <--- READ SOME OF THIS LINE = SOURCE
db2 restore database $SOURCE taken at $DB2TIME into $TARGET
```

Answer (score 0):

@pax @dennis @pavanlimo Sorry I made a typo when I was writing this,

I need to be able to read $DB2TIME after I execute:

```
db2 backup db $SOURCE online compress include logs
```

I get the output:

```
The timestamp for this backup image is : 20100906142221
```

I need to turn the 20100906142221 into $DB2TIME so I can execute the next command

```
db2 restore database $SOURCE taken at $DB2TIME into $TARGET
```